# PDF of sample mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm studying for my finals and came across the following question:

> Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be iid with PDF $f_X(x)$ and sample mean $\overline X$. Show that $$f_\overline X(x)=nf_{X_1+\cdots+X_n}(nx).$$

After trying myself I got the same result except for the factor of $n$. I find that factor suspicious as I imagine for sufficiently large $n$ we couldn't have that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_\overline X(x)\;\text{d}x=1.
$$

Is this true and is the factor of $n$ wrong or am I just being dumb?

Comment: What does $f_{X_1,\cdots,X_n}(nx)$ mean?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry I meant the sum of the random variables, I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(\overline {X_m} \leq x)=P(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n \leq nx)$. Whe you differentiate this using Chain Rule you get $f_{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n} (nx) \frac d {dx} (nx)$. So the factor of $n$ comes from Chain Rule.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I'm wondering what is wrong with my method. I reasoned that the sample mean equalling $x$ is the same as sum of the RV's equalling $nx$, and thus the chance of these two events should be equal and no factor of $n$ would be needed.

Comment: That argument  works for the distribution function, it doesn't give you the density,

Comment: Hmm, I don't exactly get what you mean. What is the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately intution alone doesn't suffice in Probability Theory. It can give wrong answers sometimes. For example if three r.v 's are independent when taken two at a time we may feel intuitivey that the three are together independent , but that is false. That is why we have to combine rigorous meaure theory with intution. @J.S.A.Frugte

Comment: Ah okay, thus my love-hate relationship with probability continues haha

Answer (score 1):

It actually seems to be correct, since
$$\mathbb{P}(\overline{X}\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(S:=\sum_i{X_i}\leq nt)$$
and deriving over the variable $t$ you get
$$f_{\overline{X}}(t)=n \ f_S(nt)$$

The latter concern is understandable but it should work fine nevertheless, it's one of those cases where the theory takes care of itself, because they're all IID and so it does the trick. I found [this pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Esheffield/2018600/Lecture22.pdf) that should come handy!